# If suppressing a file ending, does it need a redirect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

If i hide file ending of, say, PHP files, should i use a redirect? For urls like `http://example.com/product.php` changing to `http://example.com/product` I saw both variants:

- with redirect: `RewriteRule ^(.+).php$ $1 [NC,L,R=301]`
- and without: `RewriteRule ^(.+).php$ $1 [NC,L]`

Is it a "real" url change? In this case i would say it needs redirect. Or is it the same url, just with suppressed file ending, which doesn't need a redirect?

Comment: Depends on what you actually want to achieve. An "internal rewrite" takes an incoming request URL and "translates" it to the local structure of objects (for example the file system). An "external redirect" takes an incoming request and sends back a redirection which the client follows to request the target URL it has been redirected to. So the rewrite leaves the URL in the browser unchanged, the redirect changes the visible URL.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in if i suppress the file ending as an internal rewrite, will Google count this as the same URL or as another URL, which does need a redirect?

Comment: You should get the clean URL indexed and forward the ugly URL with was long, long ago considered a "file name extension" (obsolete these days anyway).

Comment: i have now an url with file extension. This url must be change to without file extension. I think about how i do it, with 301-redirect or without.

Comment: Which is what I answered to.